# What are the nuances between ἀποδίδωμι and δίδωμι, especially in this context?

Tags: greek, word-comparison

In the following text, how does ἀποδίδωμι add a nuance that would be lost with the simpler δίδωμι? Why do you think Plato chose the former over the latter?

If we do a quick search on ἀποδίδωμι in the [Perseus lexicon](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%E1%BC%80%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%B4%CE%AF%CE%B4%CF%89%CE%BC%CE%B9&la=greek#lexicon), we find that most definitions (for the transitive use) involve a "giving back" or "return". But the first definition is "to give up". Is that the nuance I am looking for: that ἡ τοῦ ἀγαθοῦ ἰδέα gives up of its own free will power to the knower?

Would it be analogous to the difference between "to give" and "to bestow upon"?

> τοῦτο τοίνυν τὸ τὴν ἀλήθειαν παρέχον τοῖς γιγνωσκομένοις καὶ τῷ γιγνώσκοντι τὴν δύναμιν ἀποδιδὸν τὴν τοῦ ἀγαθοῦ ἰδέαν φάθι εἶναι:
>
> This, then, which furnishes truth to the objects of knowledge and gives power to the knower, you must say is the idea of the good.

([Plat. Rep. 6.508e](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0168%3Abook%3D6%3Asection%3D508e))